# Shared test playlist in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, nunit, specflow

We have a smallish team of few Automated testers and working on BDD driven test automation using following tools -

- Specflow
- NUnit
- Selenium Webdriver(C#)
- on Visual Studio 2015

Right now we have projects per individual tester sitting under a central repository. Now, say myself (Tester-A) has done 100 automated scripts and from which I want to cherry-pick 20 odd tests for a **Regression Playlist** under my Project (Project-A); I can.

**Problem:** I can cherry-pick whatever test I want from Project-A, Project-B and so on into my locally sitting **Regression Playlist**. The issue is I can't figure out a way to share this playlist with others. When I commit my code the playlist does not gets checked-in as per VS feature and sits locally on my machine. 
Is there a way by which anyone can add tests into that Regression Playlist and could be accessed by all within the team.

*Note: I know about tools like Jenkins/TeamCity which probably can do this, but as of now I am looking for a solution without them.*

Answer (score 1):

As I posted my question above I kept on exploring and found that VisualStudio saves your playlists as **.vsmdi** files. Although when you create a playlist locally and then commit your code, the other person will by default not see the playlist. 
After much digging I found that playlists also gets passed on with your commit but sits in the background. You can import the playlist by following steps below --

1. Under **Test Explorer** if you (tester-A) have created a playlist, it would be available locally as (for e.g.)Playlist-A
2. Now, say if Tester-B has to access this playlist (assuming you share a common repository and Tester-A has checked in after playlist creation).
3. Tester-B : Left-click on Playlist menu under Test Explorer and choose **Open Playlist File**. You will be directed to source folder and then import the file - *TesterA.playlist* (which is a .vsmdi file)
4. That's it and you are ready to share/import each other's playlist.